# Ajax doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post

So I have an extremely simple `$.post` function that works perfectly in all the normal browsers. But in IE (I tested 7 & 8) it just doesn't happen.

```
console.log('1');

$.post('home.php', {'a':'b'}, function(data){

    console.log('2');

});
```

When I run this in FireFox, my Firebug console shows 1, then 2.
Internet Explorer doesn't get past 1. I've had problems before where it thinks it's cross-browser because of the absence of `www` but that's not the case.

I don't see where it could be going wrong.

Also changing `input` to `{ a:'b' }` doesn't work so it can't be the variables (you'd think).

EDIT: Simplified to simpler not-working version

EDIT:

There seems to be going something wrong with the variables, when I change this:

```
$.post('home.php', {'a':'b'}, function(data){
```

to

```
$.post('home.php', function(data){
```

It works..

Comment: Not sure, but `string` might be a reserved word in IE. Maybe try changing it to something else? Also, lol @ `the normal browsers`. I feel your pain.

Comment: That sounded like it should totally be the problem, however when prefixing every variable with `abc` it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Have a look at what's happening at the network level with Fiddler, Wireshark, etc.  Maybe there's a server-side error that's preventing the response from being processed properly?

Comment: Hmm, I have no experience with these programs but I will try it out tomorrow. I thought there would be an extremely simple solution and I'm leaving work in a few minutes :(

Comment: Does it actually do the POST to home.php? Does a hit show up in your access log? Maybe the AJAX is actually being performed, but something about the response is preventing log #3 from happening.

Comment: For troubleshooting I would switch the the $.ajax function so you can use both the success, error and beforeSend callback functions. You can put logging in each one of those to see if they're being hit. Did you answer...are you seeing the ajax post on the server?

Comment: I will try the $.ajax function especially for the `error` and `beforeSend`. I have made sure the AJAX isn't being performed by logging to a text file which works in FF but nothing happens in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the debug console visible in IE?  `console.log()` will prevent the rest of the script from running on IE if the console isn't visible.

Comment: Yea, I have it open and see `1` and `2` appear simultaniously, and then nothing.

Comment: +1, with that mind this script should help that issue » http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/

Comment: Also, if that was true I wouldn't see the second `console.log()` either would I?

Comment: @Kokos: If you've discovered a solution or a workaround yourself, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I haven't, I can't figure out where they are colliding and the problem turns out to be something completely different from what I originally posted. I wanted to delete the question but I can't.